# How do I check if a list is empty or the numbers are negative in the following code?

Tags: python

I have to return the list of numbers divisible by `13` first. If the list is empty or the numbers negative then the message should be `invalid input`.

```py
my_list_1 = [12, 65, 54, 39, 102, 339, 221, 50, 70, ]

def div_13(my_list):
  my_list = numpy.array([])
  result = list(filter(lambda x: (x % 13 == 0), my_list))
  if (my_list.size != 0):
    return(result)
  else:
    return('invalid input')

print(div_13('my_list_1'))
print(div_13(''))
```

Comment: A lot of problems in your code: 1) Passing the parameter `my_list_1` as a string which is incorrect. 2) Over-writing the argument received in function 3)  An unnecessary `pass` 4) Incorrect placement of `if` statement 5) `print` after `return`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehnsion with `not` and `any()` to determine if there are any values in the list that are negative. I've also adjusted some of your other code, which was writen incorrectly. I'm not sure if the whole list has to be negative or just one number.... my solution is for just one number...

```
my_list_1 = [12, 65, 54, -39, 102, 339, 221, 50, 70]
my_list_2 = [12, 65, 54, 39, 102, 339, 221, 50, 70]

def div_13(my_list):

    result = list(filter(lambda x: (x % 13 == 0), my_list))
    if (len(my_list) > 0) and not any([number for number in my_list if number < 0]):
        return(result)
    else:
        return("invalid input")

print(div_13(my_list_1))
print(div_13(my_list_2))
print(div_13(""))
```

Ouput:

```
invalid input
[65, 39, 221]
invalid input
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like :

```
my_list_1 = [12, 65, 54, 39, 102, 339, 221, 50, 70, ]
if my_list_1:
    for num in my_list_1: 

        # checking condition 
        if num >= 0: 
           print("do your stuff") 

        else: 
            print("Negative number invalid input") 
else:
    print("list is empty invalid input")
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what the numpy array is for, but without using it what you are asking should look like this

```
def div_13(aList):

    if aList is None:
        return "empty list"

    for number in alist:
        if number < 0:
            return "negative number"

    return [x for x in alist if x % 13 == 0]
```

i used a list comprehension for your divide by 13 logic, looks more readable

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Logic to find negative number and empty list